# changing string dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I'm putting the following code specifically in the immediate window in Visual studio, it returns correctly:

```
whatToMatch.Remove((whatToMatch.IndexOf(input[i])), 1)
```

But when I put it in a program as shown below, it fails:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IsPangram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string whatToMatch = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (whatToMatch.Contains(input[i]))
                {
                    whatToMatch.Remove((whatToMatch.IndexOf(input[i])), 1);
                }
                if (whatToMatch.Length == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("pangram");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("not pangram");

        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting "whatToMatch" to change dynamically as it is correct code, but it's not changing. Why? And how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Break point, add pepper and salt to taste, shake and repeat

Comment: And for your enjoyment https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: String is immutable, all `string.remove()` does is return a new string, it doesn't modify the one you call it on, so use `whatToMatch = whatToMatch.Remove((whatToMatch.IndexOf(input[i])), 1)` instead

Comment: Thank you. I will try using a stringBuilder or use your strategy.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, convert the comment to answer if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, strings in .NET are immutable, therefore you cannot expect your string to change dynamically.

Here is a concise solution to your problem using LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace IsPangram
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static bool IsPangram(this string input)
        {
            return
                !input.ToLower()
                      .Aggregate("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToList(),
                                 (ts, c) => ts.Where(x => x != c).ToList())
                      .Any();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().IsPangram() ?
                              "Is pangram" :
                              "Is not pangram");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From msdn about `String.Remove Method (Int32, Int32)`

> It returns a new string in which a specified number of characters in
>   the current instance beginning at a specified position have been
>   deleted.

So it doesn't modify the string that call it, it return a new string.
So you should use

```
whatToMatch = whatToMatch.Remove((whatToMatch.IndexOf(input[i])), 1)
```